# How to evaluate $ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{i}{n}\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^n $ where $i=\sqrt{-1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, complex-numbers

> How to evaluate the following limit? 
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{i}{n}\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^n
> $$ 
>   Here $i=\sqrt{-1}$.

I got:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{i}{n}\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^n
= \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(i-1)^n}{n(\sqrt{2})^n}
$$ 
I know the lower part goes to infinity but what to do with the upper part? Is that usefull to use squeeze theorem or is there any simplier way?

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you wrote. Try mathjax

Comment: Express $(1+i)/\sqrt{2}=\exp(i\pi/4)$.

Comment: L.Spy  Talk of "mathjax" might be confusing to you. Sorry about that.  Mathjax is a way to format mathematical expressions so they render very nicely, like you'd see in a textbook.  [Here is a really handy tutorial for learning mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Anything you want under a square root sign, you can format as `$\sqrt{blah blah}$`.  A limit of a function f(x) from $n \to \infty$ can be written `$\lim_{n\to \infty} f(x)$`.  Just a few pointers.

Comment: If your function $f(x)$ is a fraction, you can write it as follows `$f(x) = \frac{"numerator here"}{"denominator here"}$`

Comment: Write $\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}=e^{i\pi/4}\implies (\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}})^n=e^{i\ n\pi/4}$

Comment: Thank you for help with rewriting it. I didn't know how this "in-math" symbols works

Comment: Shubham Johri- but then I still have $\frac{i}{n}$ which goes to 0 right?

Answer (score 4):

We have
$$
\left|\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right|=1
$$
Thus
$$
\left|\frac{i}{n}\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{\!n}\right|=\frac{1}{n}
$$

Comment: egreg-How it could be 1? I thought that (1+i)/√2 is one of the roots of i=(a+bi)^2

Comment: @L.Spy $\sqrt{(1/\sqrt{2})^2+(1/\sqrt{2})^2}=\sqrt{1/2+1/2}=1$. With your (more complicated) approach: since $|i|=1$, also its square roots have modulus $1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} |\frac{i}{n}\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^n|=\lim_{n\to \infty} {1\over n}=0$$therefore $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{i}{n}\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^n=0$$